# Notepad++ How to replace characters in the middle using regex

Tags: notepad++

I have about 500 files which contain something like:

```
di/V7CZ/img

di/X87S/img

di/Q1SX/img
```

etc.

So as you can see, the thing in the middle is changing in every file. I would like to change everything to:

```
di/dw/img

di/dw/img

di/dw/img
```

etc.

Comment: read more about regex. then use find & replace with regex in notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Find in files dialog (Ctrl+Shift+F or menu Search/Find in Files)

Find what: `(?<=di/)[^/]+`

Replace with: `dw`

Filters: the files you want to process, for eg. `*.txt`

Directory: your folder containing the files

Search mode: `Regular expression`